# Mails Usage on FreeRTOS (STM32L4)

Tags: stm32, c, freertos, cmsis

I have an application on STM32L4 with multiple queues and threads without problems.
I try to add a mail queue via the following function :

[image]

But it seems the linker can't find the reference :

[image]

I check my cmsis_os.h in the CMSIS_RTOS_V2 directory and i am able to find the function :

[image]

I tried to define the following definition but it can't solve my problem :

[image]

Comment: Which FreeRTOS version you are using? Or which CubeL4 firmware package?

Comment: I doesn't use directly free rtos but the wrapper from ST : CMSIS_RTOS_V2

.The firmware package is V1.17.0 (L4)

Comment: CMSIS 2.0.0 change notes indicate mail queues are deprecated and message queues can be used instead. Can you find in your cmsis_os.h?

Comment: Please post code, not pictures of code.

Answer (score -1):

Ok with the help of @Justme, i found the deprecated list here :
https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/RTOS2/html/os2MigrationFunctions.html#mig_mailQueue

[image]

So i have to use an other method. Thank's a lot

Comment: please post text / code as text/code, not picture. You've been asked to do this before!